# Is there a way to use the front camera of the mobile device? Vuforia

Tags: vuforia

Using vuforia for augmented reality in Unity. I want to use the front camera of the device instead of the back camera.

I found questions about this, but I think it is for previous versions of vuforia where front camera was an option

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them

Answer (score 0):

Front camera support has been deprecated since Vuforia 8.1 see here https://library-archive.vuforia.com/release-notes/vuforia-engine-release-notes-0.html

It is possible to feed an arbitrary camera via Vuforia Driver, but this is not trivial https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/external-camera